# Wifi Finder for Windows

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there any software which will enable me to search for close wireless networks?

Comment: Luke see if this helps: http://superuser.com/questions/359695/how-to-best-position-wifi-access-point-and-its-aerials/359742#359742

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[NetStumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/)** is the main product. See this article "[War Driving for WiFi Access](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/632)" for discussion of how to find wireless networks.

[image: image4]

Some other products are:

**[inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider)**: for x86 and x64

[image: image2]

**[Vistumber](http://www.vistumbler.net/)**: supports Windows Vista and Windows 7 with GPS Support

[image: image3]

**[Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/)**:

[image: image1]