# Is there a popular application for Windows 7 to find nearby WiFi networks?

Tags: wireless-networking, sniffing

I was wondering if we can use a third party program, besides "Network and Sharing Center," to find WiFi networks.

Is there a popular and recommended application for Windows 7 that finds WiFi networks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wifi Finder for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/52427/wifi-finder-for-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that NetStumbler is the most popular. It does not officially support Windows 7 (Thank you to paradroid for pointing that out), however I did find a site that shows how to configure it to make it work with Windows 7, and it will hopefully work for you.

http://www.netstumbler.com/downloads/

http://wlanbook.com/netstumbler-windows-7/

This one is also very popular, and pretty well reviewed.

http://download.cnet.com/inSSIDer/3000-2085_4-10848357.html?tag=mncol;1 (32-bit)

http://download.cnet.com/inSSIDer-64-bit/3000-2085_4-75317291.html?tag=mncol;2 (64-bit)

Comment: NetStumbler is my favourite.  It's particularly interesting to let it run on my laptop as I drive through town, then see the fascinating variety of SSID names ("linksys" is the most common, and I've also seen creative uses of profanities in a small-but-noticeable number of them).

Comment: @paradroid: inSSIDer.

Comment: +1, but, NetStumbler does not work on Vista onwards.  inSIDDer is needed anything after XP.

Comment: @Hello71: I left it over 5 mins to edit my comment, so I deleted it and added it again, adding the first two words.  Now I see your reply, however, I have no idea what it means.

Comment: @paradroid Thank you for the update. I will edit my answer. I also did find a site to show how to make it work.